# Compare two or more columns values only if another column value is True

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How would you compare two (or more columns) values ONLY if another column value is True.
Ideally, the output would just be True(if everything is matching correctly) False otherwise.

Something like that: `df['value1'].equals(df['value2'])` but only if df['isValid'] is true.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am a beginner with panda...

Consider the below Dataframe:

Example1:

```
isValid     value1   value2
True        50       50
True        19       19
False       48       40
```

Output should be: **True** as record one and two matches and the "isValid" column is True (meaning we have to compare the values)

Example2:

```
isValid     value1   value2
False       50       50
False       19       19
False       48       40
```

Output should be **True** (no comparison to do, nothing wrong then)

Example3:

```
isValid     value1   value2
True        50       50
False       19       19
True        48       40
```

Output should be **False** (because record 3 has value1 and value2 different)

Comment: Just filter by isValid, then do your comparison.

Comment: can you filter for true values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will do

```
df.eval('value1==value2')[df.isValid].all()
```

Comment: @WilliamW adding all at the end ?

Comment: All working fine! I am accepting your answer as this is the most readable / understandable (to me). It has also the advantage of comparing the columns you specify and not all the df columns

Answer (score 3):

here is a way:

```
df1[df1['isValid']].set_index('isValid').nunique(1).eq(1).all().all()
#True
```

Comment: I think you can edit your answer, and then we can delete our comments as this is useless for future coming people

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple function that deals with the case of all False is 'isValid' to still return the single bool `True`

```
def my_comp(df):
    u = df[df.isValid]
    if u.empty:
        return True
    else:
        return u['value1'].eq(u['value2']).all()

my_comp(df1)
#True

my_comp(df2)
#True

my_comp(df3)
#False
```

Comment: This is working fine for me, thank you for answering fast!